# JavaScript is taking only the first word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery

am stuck over a small issue here.

I want to set the value of a input using JavaScript but jQuery is not displaying the full sentence.

```
var name = "Richard Keep";
```

But when I use try to do this

```
$('input#nameid').val(name)
```

to this input

```
<input type="text" id="nameid">
```

the value is set to **Richard** alone instead of **Richard Keep**. 
How do I make the jQuery echo the entire string and not just the first word in a string? Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
<td id="To_be_collected_port" onclick="requestPopup()" class="tr-selected">
   <div class="pop-td To_be_collected_port">
   </div>
   this is the content am fetching
</td>
```

This will display **this** only.

```
var str = $('#To_be_collected_port').text();
```

then

```
$('.xyz').html("<input type=\"text\" name=\"text\" id=\"selected-service-text\" value="+str+">");
```

Comment: That behaviour is very strange - I can't replicate it at all: http://jsfiddle.net/jq8x09f7/ Can you post a working example which shows the problem. Does the `input` have a `maxlength` property? Showing your full code may help narrow down the problem.

Comment: This is really weird. Are you sure your code is fine? Can you reproduce this issue @ jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue? It's not possible, so probably either `name` is in fact `Richard` or something else is interfering.

Comment: input maxlength, or name.charCodeAt(7); is not a space, or the input has a width style that hide the whole content.

Comment: Check your input type maxlength

Comment: You should have posted some code along with the question.

Comment: You should also avoid using the name of JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods, such as "name"

Comment: I have edited my question. I have not set the maxlength

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing escaped double quotes around the `value` attribute:

```
value="+str+"
```

should be:

```
value=\""+str+"\"
```

[Fiddle - works now](http://jsfiddle.net/fmytvxnc/)

*Explanation of why it was displaying "this"*

This means your input tag is effectively composing to this:

```
<input type="text" ... value=this is the content am fetching>
```

- `value` = "this"
- `is`, `the`, `content`, `am`, `fetching` = attributes without any value

Comment: This has done the magic. Thank you. (Psst, I know we are not supposed to thank someone but you have no idea what I have been through)

Comment: Although quoting attributes is optional in HTML, things like this are the reason why I insist all attributes are properly quoted in any projects I work on.

Answer (score 2):

That is odd behaviour. Here are a few things you can try

1) add a console log just before putting the value in the field. if it does not properly show the entire name then you probably have some code manipulating the variable.

```
console.log(name);
$('input#nameid').val(name);
```

2) stupid suggestion but is your input field visually not to small? Maybe it added the entire name but you just don't see it.

3) use an onchange event on the field to check if something was changed after you updated the input field.

Comment: console.log(name) displays the fullname but the problems comes inside the input box. The input maxlength is not set to anything.

Comment: if nothing is set there should be no problem adding 2 names in an input. provide more code or a jsfiddle to simulate your problem. With what you provided we can only guess the problem.